# Create too large array in C++, how to solve?

Tags: c++

Recently, I work in C++ and I have to create a `array[60.000][60.000]`. However, i cannot create this array because it's too large. I tried `float **array` or even `static float array` but nothing is good. Does anyone have an ideas? 
Thanks for your helps!

Comment: If you really need an array this big I suggest looking at using a memory mapped file.  Your OS will only map in the pages you access if you can't fit the whole thing into memory.

Comment: Also, you *are* on a 64 bit OS, right?

Comment: Yes, i'm using windows 64-bits

Comment: What are you trying to do with all that data in memory at one time? Is it important to have all of it? How could it be reorganised into smaller chunks?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's this behemoth for?  And to think I was worried about passing a few MB as a `char[]` array!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A matrix of size `60,000 x 60,000` has `3,600,000,000` elements.

You're using type `float` so it becomes:

```
60,000 x 60,000 * 4 bytes = 14,400,000,000 bytes ~= 13.4 GB
```

Do you even have that much memory in your machine?

---

Note that the issue of stack vs heap doesn't even matter unless you have enough memory to begin with.

---

**Here's a list of possible problems:**

- You don't have enough memory.
- If the matrix is declared globally, you'll exceed the maximum size of the binary.
- If the matrix is declared as a local array, then you will blow your stack.
- If you're compiling for 32-bit, you have far exceeded the 2GB/4GB addressing limit.

Comment: How it it failing? Error message? Crash?

Comment: "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way." I use devC and it's what i got zzz.

Comment: @Mysticial - it's likely a limit imposed by the compiler/linker on the BSS.

Comment: Can you show us how you are declaring the array, if you're doing `float array[60000][60000]`, then you will blow your stack. (Or if it's a global, you might exceed the compiler's limits.)

Comment: @Kingfisher I bet you had `float array[60000][60000]` at the global scope. That will break everything since there's a limit to how large the binary can be.

Comment: This is the way i create array: "float **array" "array = new float*[60000]" "for(int i = 0; i < 60000; i++){ array[i] = new float[60000]} "

Comment: You ***are*** compiling for 64-bit right? If not, then that's the problem.

Comment: yes, but how i solve it? Maybe i should try to use std::vector?

Comment: To clarify: Are you compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit? You ***need*** to compile for 64-bit. Using `std::vector` is not going to magically make `13.4 GB` fit into a 32-bit address space.

Comment: Compiling for 32/64-bit is a completely different matter from whether the OS is 32/64-bit. You need *both* a 64-bit OS and to compile for 64-bit. But based on your other comment, you only have 4GB of ram. So you will not be able to make a matrix of this size.

Answer (score 3):

Does "60.000" actually mean "60000"? If so, the size of the required memory is `60000 * 60000 * sizeof(float)`, which is roughly 13.4 GB. A typical 32-bit process is limited to only 2 GB, so it is clear why it doesn't fit.

On the other hand, I don't see why you shouldn't be able to fit that into a 64-bit process, assuming your machine has enough RAM.

Comment: yeap, i have >20GB HDD and 4GB ram

Comment: @Kingfisher 4GB of ram? So you're relying on swap?!?!?

Comment: @Kingfisher - That's your problem - you're confusing memory (RAM) with hard disk space, which are both different things.

Answer (score 1):

To initialise the 2D array of floats that you want, you will need:

60000 * 60000 * 4 bytes = 14400000000 bytes

Which is approximately 14GB of memory. That's a LOT of memory. To even hold that theoretically, you will need to be running a 64bit machine, not to mention one with quite a bit of RAM installed.

Furthermore, allocating this much memory is almost never necessary in most situations, are you sure no optimisations could be made here?

EDIT:

In light of new information from your comments on other answers: You only have 4GB memory (RAM). Your operating system is hence going to have to page at least 9GB on the Hard Drive, in reality probably more. But you also only have 20GB of Hard Drive space. This is barely enough to page all that data, especially if the disk is fragmented. Finally, (I could be wrong because you haven't stated explicitly) it is quite possible that you're running a 32bit machine. This isn't really capable of handling more than 4GB of memory at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate the memory at runtime -- consider using a memory mapped file as the backing.  Like everyone says, 14 gigs is a lot of memory.  But it's not unreasonable to find a computer with 14GB of memory, nor is it unreasonable to page the memory as necessary.

With a matrix of this size, you will likely become very curious about memory access performance.  Remember to consider the cache grain of your target architecture and if your target has a TLB you may be able to use larger pages to relieve some TLB pressure.  Then again, if you don't have enough memory you'll likely care only about how fast your storage I/O is.

If it's not already obvious, you'll need an architecture that supports a 64-bit address space in order to access this memory directly/conveniently.

Comment: A memory mapped file "bites" into the virtual memory address space of the process. So a 32-bit process won't be able to access more than 2 GB (or 4 GB when "large address space aware") _at a time_ even with memory mapped files. 64-bit process will, but it will also be able to address that much memory directly, which defeats the purpose of using memory mapped file. OTOH, if the goal is to selectively load pieces of actual physical file on as-needed basis, without mapping too much of the file at any given time, then memory mapped file is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I did a workaround where I chopped the array into sections (my biggest allowed array was *float A_sub_matrix_20[62944560]*). When I declared just one of these in main(), it seems to be put in RAM as I got a runtime exception as soon as main() starts. I was able to declare **20** buffers of that size as global variables which works (looks like in global form they are stored on the HDD - when I added A_sub_matrix_20[n] to the watch list in VisualStudio it gave a message *"reading from file"*).