# Segmentation fault in creating 2D array of large size in c++

Tags: c++

I have allocated a 2D array of size 5000 x 4859 using `new()` in C++ from a file.

```
class input
{
public :
int **mytable;
int rows;
int columns;

input()
{
   rows=5008;
   columns=4859;


     std::ifstream file("test.txt");
     mytable=new int *[rows];

      for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
      {
             mytable[i]=new int [columns];
      }

// read the input and inserted them into the array.
}
int ** gettable()
{
   return mytable;
}
```

Then  in another function where am using `mytable` through a pointer.

```
void someFunction()
{
int ** table;
input file;
table= file.gettable();

// doing neccessary operations.

}
```

When I decrease the size of the table to 500 x 500, it works fine but for large size it gives an std:: bad alloc error . Where did I go wrong? Please help.

Comment: bad_alloc == you can not allocate more memory

Answer (score 2):

This should be of help,[Creating large arrays in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527465/create-too-large-array-in-c-how-to-solve). Some relevant things you can think about when creating your arrays. 
{Though I can run and work with a 4000 by 4000 array of array (possibly because of the system configuration), it fails for 40000 by 40000.}

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to allocate too much memory. Please take a look at [bad_alloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc):

> std::bad_alloc is the type of the object thrown as exceptions by the allocation functions to report failure to allocate storage.

Obviously you exceed the allowed memory limit of your operating system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how should I create a 2D matrix as large as this?